# Any suggestions to optimize this query

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, sql-update

I'm using MySQL 5.5, and i have the following sql:

```
UPDATE t SET val = 1  WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM temp1);
UPDATE t SET val = 2  WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM temp2 );
UPDATE t SET val = 3  WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM temp3 );
UPDATE t SET val = 4  WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM temp4 );
UPDATE t SET val = 5  WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM temp5 );
UPDATE t SET val = 6  WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM temp6 );
UPDATE t SET val = 7  WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM temp7 );
UPDATE t SET val = 8  WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM temp8 );
UPDATE t SET val = 9  WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM temp9 );
UPDATE t SET val = 10 WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM temp10 );
```

the temps are TEMPORARY tables that i use, the table have around 10k entries, and it takes about 30 seconds to complete the execution of this sql statement. Also the sum of all entries from the temp tables are equal to the number of entries in t.

could i have some advices on how to optimize this?

Thanks.

Comment: share how the temp tables are populated. We may be able to reduce it to a single query that pulls from source data. This will be more efficient because it will be able to use indexes from source data and fit in a single atomic action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check if there are index on "t" for `id` column (primary key is the best index)

then try to benchmark your variant with following:

1.

```
update t, (
select 1 as v, id from temp1
union all
select 2, id from temp2
...
) as q set val=q.v where t.id=q.id
```

2.

```
truncate table t; -- note deletion of all from table t
insert into t (id, val)
select id, val from temp1
union all
select id, val from temp2
...
```

Comment: The main problem for relational database is looking whether particular value is in table or not, to do this you have to compare your value with all values in table, so you have to do up to N comparisons. And there is no other way (as we must be sure that value in table or not). But if we have sorted values in table - we can use trick "binary search", this will need only log2N comparisons, but data must be sorted. So if you have 1024 values you can either have 1024 cmp, or log2(1024) = 10 cmp, 100 times faster